# how to increase the size of /var/log/cron on cent os 6.4

Tags: centos, cron

how to increase the size of /var/log/cron on cent os 6.4. I wanted to keep the logging history longer.

Thanks!

Comment: answer: add more space to /var/log/cron on cent os 6.4! 
Please provide more information (use of lvm?).

Comment: Check `/etc/logrotate.d/syslog` and customise according to your requirements.  The issue is a frequency-of-rotation one, not a size one.

Comment: @MadHatter Thank you a lot! Your suggestion really helped me. This is what i was searching for. again thank you. 
Can i do the same with  /etc/logrotate.conf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of your cron log is limited by

- The amount of disk space available to /var/log
- The configuration of logrotate.

It's not clear which of these you're having problems with.

For the former - add more disk space.
For the latter look at the configuration of [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) the default files for which are `/etc/logrotate.conf` and `/etc/logrotate.d/*`.

If you only want to act upon cron.log you will have to remove it from it's current configuration file (see `/etc/logrotate.d/syslog`) and create a new file that tells logrotate how to handle cron.log differently.

Comment: Thank you @lain! /etc/logrotate.d/syslog this is what i was looking for.